# Problema con Array PHP

Tags: php, array

No tengo mucha experiencia en PHP. Tenía un foreach sacando la información de este Array:

```
foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
```

Ahora he añadido esto al Array:

```
foreach($_SESSION[$clie]["cart_item"] as $k => $v)
```

Y no se como cambiar las claves $k y $v para que siga funcionando. Alguien puede ayudarme?

Comment: ¿Qué es `$clie`?

Comment: tengo una duda respecto a tu snippet, te estas asegurando que en la nueva estructura del array tienes los mismos elementos disponibles ?

Comment: $clie es una variable que utilizo para que cada cliente tenga su propio cart_item

Comment: Si, el unico cambio es añadir $clie para que se genere un array diferente para cada cliente

Comment: Si ya lo estás guardando en una `$_SESSION` eso va a ser único para cada cliente. No entiendo qué intentas hacer.

Comment: $_SESSION[clie] se renueva cada vez que cambio de cliente, con lo que si que hay un $cart_item para cada $clie. La idea es una pagina donde generar pedidos, voy añadiendo productos y este foreach me comprueba si el proyecto ya estaba para modificar la cantidad.

Comment: has un `var_dump()` a `$_SESSION[$clie]["cart_item"]` y a `$_SESSION[$clie]` y añadelo a tu pregunta para ver su estructura

Answer (score 1):

Me imagino que tienes estructurado de esta manera:

**$clie** es un array de propiedades del cliente y
**cart_item** es el carrito del cliente

Dentro de **cart_item** tienes los articulos($k) y las cantidades($v)
y lo que quieres es eliminar o cambiar articulos y sus respectivas cantidades...

Si es asi, necesitas cambiar los valores por referencia o crear un nuevo array... ejemplo:

```
$cart = $_SESSION[$clie]['cart_item'];

foreach($cart as $item => $valor){
   // Cambiar valor
   $cart[$item] = 'Nuevo valor';

   // O si deseas eliminar un item
   unset($cart[$item]); 

   // Tambien por referencia 
   unset(&$item);
}
```

***El amperstamp hace el la referencia a la variable, dale una estudiada a parametros por referencia y valor.***

Hay funciones como *array_key_exists()* o *array_search()*, etcetera... para manipular los ARRAY, aqui la documentacion de las: [Funciones array de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/ref.array.php)

Lo que si necesitas explicarte mas detallado, porque no sabemos que cambios quieres hacer.

Comment: Yo te recomendaria que adjuntaras links de la documentacion al respecto de lo que respondes, de cada una de las funciones, etc. Para hacerla lo mejor documentada posible. Saludos

Comment: Listo!! puse un link con todas las funciones array de PHP. Espero que sirva para resolver esta duda.

Comment: Gracias!! He conseguido arreglarlo así :-) Siento haberme explicado tan mal y haber puesto tan poca información... en esto a veces pensamos que nos estamos explicando bien y hay mucho contexto y no nos damos cuenta jeje